# UIViewController implementing protocol as parameter or return type

Tags: swift3, swift-protocols

I have a pattern where I create UIViewControllers that implement a certain protocol. Because I need them to be real UIViewControllers to be able to push them on the stack they always need to be UIViewControllers not some random class implementing the protocol.

At first I thought I could limit the protocol, but I couldn't figure that out. If you have any idea how to solve it at the source, that would even be better. However as a return type it seemed I was more lucky:

https://briancoyner.github.io/2015/11/14/swift-protocol-that-returns-protocol.html

```
protocol ModalViewControllerProvider {

    typealias V: UIViewController, ModalPresentationCompletion

    func viewControllerWithObject(object: AnyObject) -> V
}
```

This example doesn't work in Swift 3 however, and I couldn't get it to work except with protocol composition, which doesn't work for UIViewController.

I can work around it by return a UIViewController then casting to ModalPresentationCompletion but that's a bit weird for other programmers to recognize.

Can I assure either in the declaration of the protocol itself, or by creating something like a typealias like above a way to ensure that it's both a UIViewController and a certain protocol is always implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the last changes this type alias looks like this:

```
typealias V = UIViewController & ModalPresentationCompletion
```

Tested in Swift 4

Comment: This is new in Swift 4 right? Or is this also the Swift 3 syntax?

Comment: Now I can't verify on Swift 3. It may be working in both dialects but I can't guarantee this.

Comment: Well I wasn't interested in a Swift 3 answer anymore anyway! So thanks!